# Which of these favored class/race options should I take for my magus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a human of level 1 Myrmidarch Magus that will eventually turn to a Myrmidarch Magus 8 / Arcane Archer 10 + 2 more level of something.

I have the option of taking 1/4 * magus level in bonus arcane pool, to a total of 2 bonus.
8 total levels of magus and an estimated 6 intelligence bonus will give me a base of 10.

Alternatively, I could get humans' favored race bonus of +1 health for a +8 health. For d8 with an average of 4.5 each level except the first which is max and with 3 con would give me at level 8 ~64 hp. That 8 extra hp would mean 12.5% more, but as a ranged character I would think that taking damage would be either my mistake or an inevitability but in the end, be a rare occurrence.

Due to my unfamiliarity of pathfinder mechanics and progression in ecls vs party, I can't tell if that 8 hp will come in handy or not.
At the same time, those 2 points of arcane pool might come in handy. From 10 to 12 is a 20% increase in daily power output and I have yet to find items or potions to regenerate arcane pool and if there are any, I am sure I won't have at-will access to them. No ye old magic shops around.

Taking a feat for extra arcane pool is situational and I have a chance once every two levels, but this choice I must take now and remains locked for the rest of this character's lifespan. And beyond :D

Comment: When you say that you're locked into your choice, what do you mean? (It's a common misreading of the rules that you can't choose a different favoured bonus each level, but it's not true.)

Comment: nono, it means that, should I take 1 hp at a level, then I would have 7 levels for 1/4 arcane pool, rounded down would be only 1 arcane pool and a waste of 3 levels.

Comment: I usually take extra skill points myself. 1/4 arcane pool always seemed a little low to me. If you're a Magus/Arcane Archer you're going to have, hopefully, a high Dex and Int anyway, which means your arcane pool should be substantial just on Int alone and your AC should be high as well.

Comment: @Discipol Ok, I thought it might be that; then we're all on the same page!

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the HP bonus as there is a way to get additional arcane pool points in the form of a 20,000gp ring available(in Ultimate Equipment) by the name of Ring of Arcane Mastery. It allows you to store 4 pool points that remain until used, much like a Ring of Spell Storing.

Comment: *Rastafarian voice* that be quite expensive mon!

Comment: True, and if you are thus worried about gold cost, then as an alternative, a Belt of Mighty Constitution could serve as the alternative(which would let you put your favoured bonus into Arcane Pool. I mentioned/favoured the ring specifically as you mentioned a lack of finding of items that could boost/refuel the Arcane Pool.

Comment: yeah but even with said belt, would 2 arcane points make a difference? I plan on getting belt of battle if that is still around. another fullround per day can make the difference.

Comment: Belt of battle never got added into pathfinder, for good reason.